# ggplot within customized function

Tags: r, ggplot2, customization

I am trying to create a customized function to generate ggplots. It seems that the `y = ..prop..` can not be recognized by the customized function. I wonder whether there is any way to get around it?

```r
line_by_seg <- function(inputdata, input_x, colorgrp) {
  inputdata$input_x <- inputdata[, input_x]
  inputdata$colorgrp <- inputdata[, colorgrp]
  g <- ggplot(inputdata, 
              aes_string(x = input_x, y = ..prop.., color = colorgrp, group = colorgrp), 
              environment = environment()) +
    geom_freqpoly(stat = "count") 
}

data <- data.frame(LOB = c("mono", "mult", "mult", "mono", "mono"), 
                   segments = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B") 
)

line_by_seg(data, "LOB", "segments")
```

This code gives the error below:

> Error in aes_string(x = input_x, y = ..prop.., color = colorgrp, group = colorgrp) :
> object '..prop..' not found

If I replace the `y=..prop..`, the function works.

```r
line_by_seg <- function(inputdata, input_x, colorgrp, test) {
  inputdata$input_x <- inputdata[, input_x]
  inputdata$colorgrp <- inputdata[, colorgrp]
  inputdata$test <- inputdata[, test]
  g <- ggplot(inputdata, 
              aes_string(x = input_x, color = colorgrp, group =  colorgrp),
              environment = environment()) +
    geom_freqpoly(stat = "count") 
}

data$test <- c(1:5)
line_by_seg(data, "LOB", "segments", "test")
```

And `..prop..` also works outside of a customized function.

Comment: `aes_string` accepts strings. So use `"..prop.."`, or the more modern `"stat(prop)"`, including the `"`.

Comment: Hi Axeman, the quotes worked for both options you mentioned. Thank you so much! Now I can cut more than half of my codes using customized functions.